# how to make a dockerfile with only one container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a yii1 application. And I have a dockerfile. And I had a docker-compose file.

But for the momemnt I only have one application. Because I have a remote database. So the database is not in a container.

So I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

#COPY BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/AzureDB.crt

# Copy virtual host into container
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Enable rewrite mode
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install \
    libzip-dev \
    wget \
    git \
    unzip \
    -y --no-install-recommends

# Install PHP Extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql

# RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug-3.1.3 \
#     && rm -rf /tmp/pear

# Copy composer installable
COPY ./install-composer.sh ./

# Copy php.ini
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

#COPY BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80

# Cleanup packages and install composer
RUN apt-get purge -y g++ \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && sh ./install-composer.sh \
    && rm ./install-composer.sh

# Change the current working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Change the owner of the container document root
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

# Start Apache in foreground
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

And I had this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:   
    build: ./docker       
    container_name: dockeryiidisc
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - C:\xampp\htdocs\webScraper/docker:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
      - C:\xampp\htdocs\webScraper:/var/www/html/
```

and that worked.

But so now I only want to use the dockerfile.

So I tried this:

```
docker build -t docker_webcrawler .
```

and this command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name cntr-apache docker_webcrawler
```

But if I then go to: `http://localhost:80`

I only see a empty directory:

```
Index of /
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
```

So what I have to change? That I only have to use the dockerfile?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the volume mappings that you have in your docker-compose file. Try this

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name cntr-apache -v C:\xampp\htdocs\webScraper/docker:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ -v C:\xampp\htdocs\webScraper:/var/www/html/ docker_webcrawler
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. But is there a command that I can put the mapping in the dockkerfile?

Comment: No. Docker is very strict about only letting whoever *runs* the image decide what the image can access on the host computer. If it were in the Dockerfile, it would be whoever *built* the image that decided it. That's why you can safely pull images from docker hub and run them, since they can only access whatever you let them.

Comment: Oke, But I want to deploy the dockerfile to Azure. And in Azure you only have the dockerfile. Or they say it is better to only have the dockerfile. Then you every time have to fill in the path?

Comment: I don't know the particulars of what your image does, but maybe you can `COPY` the files from the host into the image.